# Android: Populate ScrollView with foreach

Tags: android, xamarin, scrollview

my issue is quite simple: I am having a list with 5 objects in it and I want to show them in a scrollview. I am doing this like here:

```
    private void PopulateScrollView(List<string> content)
    {
        LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.scrollview);

        foreach(string obj in content)
        {
            LinearLayout ln = new LinearLayout(this);
            TextView txt = new TextView(this);
            txt.Text = obj;
            txt.TextSize = 20;
            txt.Click += delegate
            {
                Android.Net.Uri uri2 = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(obj);
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.Create(this, uri2);
                mediaPlayer.Start();
            };

            ln.AddView(txt);
            root.AddView(ln);

        }
    }
```

And my XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="80"
    android:layout_height="0dp">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/scrollview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now, the problem is the following: Instead of now showing 5 objects in my scrollview, my app is just showing the first object and then ignors the others. I know that my list is working from the debugger: it contains all objects. The loop is being executed 5 times, so that is working fine as well. But only the first object is visible in the scrollview. Where is my mistake?

Thanks!

Comment: Try with changing the orientation of LinearLayout in xml from "horizontal" to "vertical"

Comment: thats it! (prv comment got deleted...) thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Your LinearLayout ln is created by default with match_parent/match_parent, so only 1 row occupies the full screen. If you scroll it you can find the rest. Solution is to specify wrap_content in height for LinearLayout ln.